# Should integration test bypass login natural processes in order don't retest same login functionality for many times

Tags: testing, bdd, scenarios

Let's say I'm testing a web service and I have a couple of scenarios requires user to be authenticated:

```
Scenario #1: Customer sign-up

Scenario #2: Customer sign-in

Scenario #3: Customer change name

Scenario #4: Customer update image
```

Should all the tests go through all login steps like:

```
1) Go to register page
2) Enter new user information
3) Activate account
4) Go to login page
5) Enter login and password
6) Press the Login button
7) Check if I authenticated as a customer
```

Or I can just test it once and implement endpoint which quickly creates a user and log it in.

So if I have that kind of endpoint that means I can skip retesting the same things all the time and just have short scenarios #3 and #4 implementation. But in this case, I have a less natural environment.

Please tell me about the **best practices** that you use in real projects.

Comment: Can logging a user in be accomplished by calling one of the web service end points? Are these tests automating a user interface, or just making direct calls to web services?

Answer (score 0):

Few best practices:

- use the **testing pyramid** `integration` > `ui` (tests are much slower on UI, automate in the UI only the necessary things to have main flows covered)
- for the UI use fast methods for the setup (so yes, web services, test login only once)
- if possible keep some test data trough the builds (for example to make sure a new build that might change data structure does not affect basic functionality, e.g. login)
- tests should be atomic (not depend on each other)
- do some cleanup from time to time to remove duplicate test code and to improve the framework(speed, stability)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't copy and paste the "log in" scenario to all of the other scenarios, but having an account and being logged in *are* prerequisites for the other use cases. From a behavior driven development perspective this will translate to one or more `Given` steps that simulate or actually perform those steps:

```
Scenario: Customer change name
    # Calls web service or database to create new user
    Given "Bob" is a registered user

    # Calls web service or database to make account active
    And "Bob" has an active account

    # Opens browser, navigates to login page, fills out login form and submits it
    And the user is logged in as "Bob"

    # Steps specific to changing name and asserting it has changed
    When the user changes their name to "Samuel"
    Then the user's name is "Samuel"
```